# How to add an anchor to a div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a series of div elements set up like this:

```
<div id="step-1" class="circle">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

And the classes:

```
.circle {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

The above simulates a stepper and looks like this:

[image: Stepper]

I would like to add an anchor to the `circle` element only, so that the user can click on the circle to jump immediately to that step instead of click a `Back` button multiple times.

How can I do it?

Comment: So you want your div to be a link instead? Or do you want a link that goes to the div?

Comment: Whatever works! I only want to the circle to be a link and not the line.

Comment: Well your code doesn't include css for the line. Also you have one too many double quotes after class circle

Comment: If you wrap the outer div within an <a>, it will encompass the inner divs as well, there’s no other way around it. But what you can do is explain what you need this for, in which case, there might a different way to achieve the final goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the circles in a div, and set the position to relative;

Then position the line's top to align it properly and give it a z-index of -1. That will place it behind the circles.

```css
.circles{
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:100px;
}

.circle.active{
  background-color:green;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -2px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <a href="#" id="step-1" class="circle active"></a>
  <a href="#" id="step-2" class="circle"></a>
  <a href="#" id="step-3" class="circle"></a>
  <a href="#" id="step-4" class="circle"></a>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```